# How to use IndexOf in a JSON array? It's returning -1

Tags: arrays, json, indexof

Let's say I'm searching this JSON array for the car model "Focus"
and I want to return its position in the array.

I think `indexOf` is returning a result of -1 because I'm not stopping the loop. I'm a beginner coder.

The reason I want to return its position is so I can return other results related to "Focus" such as "Ford" by simply knowing its position in the array.

```js
var myObj, i, j, x = "";
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
}

for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
    for (j in myObj.cars[i].models) {
    x = myObj.cars[i].models[j];
    a = x.indexOf("Focus");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
   }
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than deal with two different for-loops, use one and try to get the index of whatever each iteration. Test the value of `x` for -1 (meaning not found). If it isn't -1, that means it was found, and `x` is the index.

```
for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
    x = myObj.cars[i].models.indexOf("Focus");

    if (-1 != x) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` breaks the for-loop so in the case of collision you'll just get the first valid index.

**Edit**

As a side-note I thought I'd mention what your problem really was: Your `indexOf()` call is returning a value, but you aren't checking it for `-1` values. In your original code, if you tested that `a != -1` it would only confirm `a == "Focus"` and not give you any details on its index. In the end, for a minimal edit, you would need to do

```
if (-1 != a) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = j;
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
if ("Focus" == x) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this as a potential solution, but for some reason it returns no result for me.

Comment: Sorry, I used `return` thinking this was taking place within a function. You can use `break` to quit the for-loop and that should work outside a function. I'll modify my answer for this case.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First i would parse the json with JSON.parse method.

*Attention: I am using ECMAScript 6 (ES6) Feature here to use multiline strings. This is not supported by older browsers.*

Then i would make use of the Array Prototype functions like `map()` and `find()` to first map the index of all models with 'Focus' to a new array and then take the first where the index is 0 or higher. `indexOf()` Returns -1 when the element your looking for does not exist.

```js
var json = `{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
}`

var myObj = JSON.parse(json)

var focusIndex = myObj.cars.map(c => c.models.indexOf('Focus')).find(i => i >= 0)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = focusIndex
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm not an experienced coder, but I assumed there was a basic solution to this that I'm missing.

Comment: I do not see a simpler way to do this. But this solution seems much better than iterating over the array and subarray with a 'for'-loop. There is a findIndex() function on array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) but you cannot take advantage of it in your case. Because you need the index of the 'Focus' model in the models array. If you would need the index of the model in the car array which contains a 'Focus' you could you use findIndex()